# How to correctly terminate multiprocessing.Process()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I've a code that needs to run multiple parallel threads in the following way :

```
def driver():
    #Gets a UID and passes it to Run
    run(uid)

def f1(a,b,c):
    #Does Some thing : Trivial Example Below - These Operations might take long time
    d=a+b+c
    print(d)

def f2(a,b,c):
    #Does Some thing : Trivial Example Below - These Operations might take long time
    d=a+b*c
    e=a+b/c
    print(d,e)
```

Now, I have a `run()` method that runs these in parallel.

```
from multiprocessing import Process
def run(uid):
    #Get a,b,c on the basis of UID then call the following
    thread_1=Process(target=f1, args=(a,b,c))
    thread_2=Process(target=f2, args=(a,b,c))
    thread_1.start()
    thread_2.start()
    thread_1.join()
    thread_2.join()
```

The entry point of the code is `driver()`.
However, my code gets stuck after certain number of operations and I guess it is due to a memory issue.

My question is: How can I terminate the threads correctly after their successful execution? Do they still reside in memory after execution?

Is there anything wrong in the way I'm running these threads?

Comment: As your code is now written, you are not running anything in parallel. `join()` is a blocking call. You start thread_1 (a process, not a thread, but you can of course name your variables as you like), wait for it to finish, then launch thread_2 and wait for it to finish. You should start with putting both start statements next to each other and joining processes only after you have launched them both.  But this does not answer your question, just an observation about your code.

Comment: Edited the code, so start() for each is called and then join() is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Threadpool executor or Threading library to manage things easier.

Threadpool executor can be used as follows.

```
def test(n):
 print(n)
            
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
  for i in range(10):
     executor.submit(test, args)
```

https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide.html